# How to make an opaque Activity?

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I'm using [QuickAction3D](https://github.com/lorensiuswlt/NewQuickAction3D) library and I would like to make the background sort of opaque when the QuickAction it's clicked, just like a normal AlertDialog would do, it's there a way of doing this?.

Thank you very much

**EDIT**

I meant the Activity go to an opaque color, and the quick action preserve it's current color. For example, If an AlertDialog it's shown, the background activity would be turned opaque, and the AlertDialog it's on a clear color.

Answer (score 1):

[Quich action 3d](https://github.com/lorensiuswlt/NewQuickAction3D)
See in that library for the background they have used a selector drawable [action_item_btn.xml](https://github.com/lorensiuswlt/NewQuickAction3D/blob/master/res/drawable/action_item_btn.xml), you can customize the code to make as per ur need.They have set as

```
 <item 
    android:state_pressed="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/action_item_selected"/>
```

for the background if u want to set the selector for the items in the list u can set selector for the imageView present there like,

Create a background drawable resource, e.g. `item_background.xml`, in your `/drawable` folder, containing something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:drawable="@color/color1" android:state_pressed="true"/>
  <item android:drawable="@color/color2" android:state_selected="true"/>
  <item android:drawable="@color/color3" android:state_activated="true"/>
  <item android:drawable="@color/color4"/>
</selector>
```

Then provide the color values in your `/values/colors.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
  <color name="color1">#DDff8800</color>
  <color name="color2">...</color>
  <!-- more colors... -->
</resources>
```

Finally, set that drawable resource as the item background in your layout with `android:background="@drawable/item_background"`.

Comment: that would make the whole activity opaque?, or just the button?

Comment: according to ur edit u should set bg for the file that i mentioned and set #80000000 as bg and try